# Can't add a key to superglobals from a class in a "required" file

Tags: php, oop, object, php-5.3

Background: I have an existing class with static functions that I'd like to reuse for another part of the same project. The static functions use `$_GET`, etc.

Here is the baffling code. First, the class:

```
<?php

// ./fakeapi/fakeapi.php

class FakeAPI {

    static public function test (){

        $var = '_GET';
        ${$var}['newVar'] = '123';
        print_r($_GET);

    }
}
```

And the file requiring it:

```
<?php

require_once 'fakeapi/fakeapi.php';

FakeAPI::test();

$var = '_GET';
${$var}['newVar'] = '123';
print_r($_GET);
```

prints:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [newVar] => 123
)
```

...and I have no idea why. It's not a scope issue, because if I set `$_GET['newVar'] = '123';` in the class function, it works. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Your question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176269/php-variable-variables-problem?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PHP Manual [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

> Warning
>
> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's
>   Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable
>   $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced
>   dynamically.

Comment: Wow. Who knew? I can't believe I wasted over an hour of my life over this. Thanks, you get the check mark. :)