# PHP Post vars to var names ok with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, http-post, sql-injection

Is there anything wrong with doing this? Ive looked everywhere and it doesnt seem like this is a common thing? is there a built in function im not aware of that does this? Im using PDO for inputs so I am assuming this is fine.

thanks for ANY help!!

```
foreach($_POST as $post => $var){
    ${$post} =  $var;
}
```

Comment: That's basically `extract()`. Why did you assume it is relevant to PDO?

Comment: No, don’t do this. Users can modify *any* variable with that, including $GLOBALS, $_SESSION, $_SERVER, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Warning

> As [@Gumbo stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642750/php-post-vars-to-var-names-ok-with-pdo/33642787?noredirect=1#comment55063804_33642787), this is, in no way, what you want to do. You
>   should avoid doing anything like this with super globals in any sense.
>   You're better off controlling each aspect as best as possible and
>   assigning the variables properly, as best practice permits. i.e.
>
> ```
> $a = 'derp';
> ```

---

What you're doing is called [Variable Variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and is built into PHP. It essentially allows you to dynamically create variables for use within the current scope.

Take a `$_POST` array of the following:

```
Array (
    [a] => 'derp'
)
```

Now with your current code, you'll be dynamically creating & assigning a variable:

```
foreach($_POST as $post => $var){
    ${$post} =  $var;
}
```

Which in turn, allows you to access said variable as the key:

```
echo $a; // would echo out derp
```

From personal experience, this isn't always necessary and an issue you could potentially run into is overwriting a variable that has already been set, in turn, producing unwanted/unexplained output.

---

You'd be best to have a read of these answers to gain a wider understanding of what you're currently doing:

- [Dynamic variable names in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9257505/2518525)
- [PHP Variables - Concatenate variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11740231/2518525)
- [php variable variables problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6176269/2518525) (especially worth a read if trying to harness superglobals)

Comment: Allowing users to populate arbitrary variables is rather how you get hacked: `_SESSION[user]=admin`

Comment: @Gumbo I'll modify answer to note that, was just stating exactly what OP is actually doing via using this.